# CASE Statment for USQL through ODBC in Query

Tags: sql, syntax, odbc, case

I am trying to write a CASE statement for a query, and it seems USQL doesn't actually have the Syntax for a CASE.

Just trying to find out if anyone knows of the correct fn to make a case statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation that I found (http://pz.southware.com/nlhtml/USQL_User_Guide.pdf) there is no reference to a CASE statement, so you're probably correct in saying that it doesn't support that.

There is the `isnull` function that you could use if your CASE statement condition was checking for a null value.  You could maybe simulate a case by having a nested query or two, or maybe by splitting your query into multiple parts (one for each CASE condition) and then unioning them together.  Not exactly elegant though...